# How to create auto-generated Django notification?

Tags: django, notifications

I have this problem: My web app is for tracking goals of the user, every goal has reminders, so when a reminder has expired the app must alert the user. Example, 
Mark has a goal: "Run a marathon on December" and this goal has a reminder in every Saturday at 15:00. So If Mark is using the app at 15:00 on a Saturday, the browser must alert him. This is for my university so if the solution is simple, better !

I don't know which method to try, all the examples or tutorials functions with notifications of actions of users. Here the actor is the server, I'm very lost.

What should I learn ?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-notifications-hq/

https://github.com/peterbe/django-sockjs-tornado

https://github.com/pinax/pinax-notifications

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=django%20notification%20node

If you can advise me as to how use Nodes better , that would be very helpful.
Thanks